# How to resolve url's to final destination in php

Tags: php, html, css

How do i resolve the urls like the one below:

> http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=newssearch&cd=1&ved=0CC4QqQIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usatoday.com%2Fnews%2Fworld%2Fstory%2F2011-09-18%2Findia-earthquake-fatalities%2F50456078%2F1&ei=JkF2TriYPImGrAeHxdCFDQ&usg=AFQjCNEshh4QAZQlM_tVPoT_l7rJ0ag21Q

to it's final url

> http://www.usatoday.com/news/world/story/2011-09-18/india-earthquake-fatalities/50456078/1

I've tried `curl` but it's resolving it to http://www.google.co.in/http

Comment: How do you end up with this link in the first place?

Comment: You have to use some kind of HttpBrowser, that understands redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/fc7c1/1

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=newssearch&cd=1&ved=0CC4QqQIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usatoday.com%2Fnews%2Fworld%2Fstory%2F2011-09-18%2Findia-earthquake-fatalities%2F50456078%2F1&ei=JkF2TriYPImGrAeHxdCFDQ&usg=AFQjCNEshh4QAZQlM_tVPoT_l7rJ0ag21Q');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo $info['url'];
```

Comment: thanx. it works. i guess the prob was with RETURN_TRANSFER. but u can use `curl_getinfo()` to get the url. no need to `preg_match`

Answer (score 0):

All you are after is the value of the `url` parameter.  You can `preg_split` the initial url by `/&\?/`, then take the element starting with `url=`, finally split it by `=` sign and use `urldecode` on the final value.

Comment: that url was just an example. all url's aren't like tat.

Comment: Then what is your generalised input?  Is there any rule as to how your input appears?

Comment: This maybe how it appears on a page for eg. like google. That's all i know.

Comment: Then your first step is to determine what your input is.  You can't created a program to produce specific output if you don't know what your input looks like.